# Keras get_weight() asking for clarification

Tags: python, keras, lstm

As far as my understanding, my neural network only have 2 layers LSTM and output layer, but when I print out the weight of each layer, I got one extra layer with empty weight. Can anyone clarify this output or is my understanding is wrong?

It has time_step of 7, num_input of 3, output of 2. The dropout rate is 0.5.

This neural network output even if not trained produce the same output no matter what the input is. I'm trying to debug it.

Code:

```
model.add(LSTM(12, input_shape=(time_steps, num_input), activation='relu', unit_forget_bias=True, bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomUniform(minval=-1, maxval=1), recurrent_activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
model.add(Dense(num_output, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomUniform(minval=-1, maxval=1)))
model.compile(loss=loss_function, optimizer=optimizer_function, metrics=['acc'])
counter = 0
for layer in model.layers:
    print(counter, layer.get_weights())
    counter += 1
```

Output:

```
0 [array([[-0.24521542, -0.70160842,  0.27366495, -0.27743888,  0.75009584,
         0.25599909,  0.38801599, -0.20273829, -0.07191849,  0.27447796,
        -0.00708866, -0.00666118,  0.17631078,  0.02666068, -0.07738662,
         0.33693957,  0.96345758,  0.71073961,  0.44208169,  0.6945982 ,
         0.64919782, -0.52719903,  0.12036228,  0.60486031,  0.51799178,
        -0.75186992, -0.28580689, -0.19886994,  0.49282694,  0.83806777,
         0.00712466, -0.62782884,  0.04944801,  0.7866354 ,  0.28580236,
        -0.25791597,  0.99613404,  0.72680449, -0.73945332,  0.79622149,
         0.39543009,  0.15706682,  0.58931088,  0.88239527, -0.80051279,
         0.52861094,  0.77886581,  0.80290627],
       [ 0.7546804 , -0.48624468, -0.15527534, -0.70569277,  0.86888766,
         0.48139691, -0.19293284,  0.42512822, -0.99511337,  0.03062463,
         0.12436891, -0.87743688,  0.24677491, -0.16390824,  0.05924869,
        -0.75485945, -0.51627636,  0.92178059, -0.95354581, -0.10260463,
        -0.04684424,  0.01882982, -0.62982488,  0.87434769, -0.39813781,
        -0.3045814 , -0.91332555, -0.1598289 ,  0.35212064,  0.17643642,
         0.52914667,  0.36753321, -0.05140471,  0.77591944, -0.785537  ,
         0.76745152, -0.7325809 , -0.88412356,  0.74923658, -0.30762291,
        -0.75603771, -0.8112607 , -0.91697383, -0.54521894, -0.51775885,
         0.30885959, -0.22136259, -0.66382146],
       [ 0.26065445,  0.48088837, -0.94533539,  0.01412749, -0.16286325,
         0.88329911, -0.68435764, -0.32847238, -0.3569994 ,  0.00744963,
         0.37743616, -0.8640151 ,  0.42867732, -0.71146655,  0.3011651 ,
         0.80415225, -0.98356128, -0.14065552,  0.26375103, -0.11873388,
         0.01047683,  0.40524793,  0.69572425, -0.15699077, -0.21437597,
        -0.17017817, -0.29662871, -0.61970282, -0.80687809,  0.17843056,
        -0.61833644,  0.22320771, -0.04641867,  0.50721407, -0.96682215,
        -0.95549297, -0.43905139, -0.20920539, -0.69045758,  0.24916172,
         0.71746254, -0.90135694, -0.02756333,  0.85385418, -0.17386127,
        -0.6222682 , -0.18429565,  0.38925314]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.02033471,  0.35036457, -0.22910373,  0.00760625,  0.2043882 ,
         0.11738618, -0.08864721,  0.01498185,  0.26989809,  0.21553771,
        -0.05318699, -0.22805944, -0.02447774,  0.19338799,  0.12499192,
         0.06640412,  0.07907286,  0.08237705,  0.04068918, -0.07288828,
        -0.02745646,  0.1590983 ,  0.13237894,  0.34082556, -0.1463456 ,
         0.06416136, -0.05991739, -0.18373621, -0.08630949, -0.01693073,
        -0.04433511,  0.30036968, -0.00352106,  0.01008222, -0.01238813,
        -0.09504303,  0.09013844, -0.14845927, -0.14517047,  0.14843805,
         0.11790767,  0.02793198,  0.06459343,  0.06467769,  0.06598908,
        -0.23322476, -0.03217521,  0.14322996],
       [ 0.05864402,  0.07922871,  0.07378255,  0.04546327,  0.01927931,
         0.18573418, -0.159896  ,  0.02487363,  0.02383794, -0.20636876,
        -0.02224975,  0.20493619,  0.22222976, -0.09418963,  0.0355754 ,
        -0.16385514,  0.1784135 ,  0.19803056, -0.01829438, -0.06000176,
         0.21078815, -0.22398581, -0.06617181,  0.15193403, -0.11811844,
         0.13475136, -0.31193998,  0.00333052, -0.09486151,  0.20512965,
        -0.12429255, -0.10136144,  0.0240426 , -0.0179066 , -0.22667909,
        -0.03775523,  0.0684068 ,  0.07891367,  0.02093293, -0.10532314,
         0.10350898, -0.05209668, -0.04242592, -0.36924657,  0.04319758,
        -0.2742556 ,  0.09543416, -0.18032318],
       [ 0.03556766,  0.05535906,  0.02675538, -0.02131121,  0.26054731,
        -0.09065662, -0.15470752,  0.02705213,  0.03218656, -0.28294089,
        -0.1241535 , -0.03728139,  0.05195143, -0.22098057,  0.05037116,
        -0.11720208,  0.07683843, -0.1193686 , -0.22540359, -0.16058175,
         0.04342809, -0.01308457, -0.18741629, -0.063871  , -0.02473109,
        -0.33817884, -0.01401741,  0.1469952 ,  0.02203038, -0.01378152,
         0.00996919,  0.10832896,  0.10883206, -0.0299022 ,  0.25817832,
        -0.18097696,  0.09837963, -0.26886559,  0.21029587,  0.23133136,
         0.06430923, -0.08498586,  0.3173219 , -0.0478869 ,  0.13538593,
         0.08697879, -0.09221876, -0.01162537],
       [-0.05401393,  0.06125088,  0.23440452, -0.06260482,  0.03913982,
        -0.14856239, -0.02149021,  0.21849351,  0.20043746, -0.09506505,
        -0.00982449, -0.09573822, -0.22466341,  0.22394681, -0.2147858 ,
         0.06025937, -0.03828581, -0.00167759, -0.03305264, -0.23886602,
         0.17675708, -0.0092163 , -0.0167509 ,  0.04083197,  0.08696942,
        -0.03983665, -0.03215779,  0.12096903,  0.19513203,  0.24121523,
        -0.09233849,  0.07302081,  0.1582018 , -0.02135381,  0.20214865,
        -0.2333072 , -0.13499814, -0.02135884, -0.11316242, -0.34329945,
        -0.2342732 ,  0.05534038, -0.1002339 ,  0.07087246, -0.0139307 ,
        -0.12557672,  0.25842258, -0.00906693],
       [-0.3691411 , -0.20162676,  0.02531274, -0.05095335,  0.21560751,
        -0.14882837,  0.01329543, -0.07940496, -0.06948807,  0.22213475,
        -0.24376036,  0.17134094,  0.22963829, -0.04603028, -0.07653585,
         0.06974904,  0.08805051,  0.0361966 , -0.10852201,  0.07912195,
        -0.06465252,  0.01856732,  0.21850535,  0.21364164, -0.12931682,
         0.02285584,  0.1271527 , -0.17278516,  0.07559054,  0.09732898,
        -0.04404632, -0.19681202, -0.06003241, -0.12298001,  0.11505324,
        -0.20419037, -0.2508668 , -0.1274903 ,  0.04451947, -0.07883096,
        -0.11704427,  0.18670546,  0.05032831, -0.1164139 ,  0.01936312,
        -0.02296325, -0.21579987, -0.13748147],
       [ 0.04260362,  0.00762554, -0.07162373,  0.03100744, -0.19107912,
        -0.08416328, -0.05336539,  0.03323252, -0.01961052,  0.40443578,
        -0.24548431,  0.05731211,  0.05728706, -0.05157589,  0.00268018,
        -0.1519298 , -0.06639624,  0.15809853, -0.00273514, -0.41929573,
         0.02783292,  0.0678527 ,  0.08088325,  0.01352766,  0.18033364,
         0.22313675,  0.08921089,  0.10697351,  0.22069024,  0.00937657,
         0.01461298,  0.01710716,  0.21329141,  0.06096657, -0.13535568,
        -0.01004616, -0.0111774 ,  0.06089412,  0.19857614, -0.05482864,
         0.08520801, -0.26553917,  0.20397952, -0.14985719,  0.05710589,
         0.16448419,  0.01346221,  0.18271512],
       [-0.05295208,  0.2243471 ,  0.17107718, -0.30323064, -0.00788007,
        -0.11950868,  0.24900137, -0.21288717, -0.03036776,  0.11939076,
        -0.02417958,  0.02557938,  0.03513969, -0.02777558, -0.06980747,
        -0.0185275 , -0.06350167,  0.01700263, -0.22184421, -0.06240473,
         0.12922326,  0.37910423, -0.11080422, -0.13848746,  0.02415096,
        -0.17376019,  0.0525399 , -0.08634372, -0.15843505,  0.05735993,
        -0.09645485, -0.06318427, -0.09628739, -0.00575478, -0.37868378,
        -0.06525372,  0.25985357, -0.17358606, -0.06864014, -0.08131886,
         0.03705063,  0.10135308,  0.04662868, -0.07647421, -0.15614538,
         0.05403953,  0.16817404, -0.08463066],
       [ 0.17623845, -0.15794764, -0.04160334, -0.13513324,  0.21663484,
         0.19407599,  0.10787451, -0.02537039,  0.12182101,  0.03565344,
         0.17000458,  0.00349261,  0.02175007,  0.08370995,  0.11974211,
         0.14470729, -0.08181615,  0.0552465 , -0.13478576, -0.05293605,
         0.21553941, -0.32911152,  0.06520491,  0.04304377,  0.03740592,
        -0.01165924,  0.15674426,  0.09790639, -0.01096018, -0.11590454,
        -0.0511469 ,  0.23025918, -0.02462219, -0.26048404, -0.30032566,
         0.08880173, -0.29021269, -0.00818963,  0.04883815,  0.01467158,
        -0.12270398,  0.19118902,  0.29459879, -0.02962655, -0.02923334,
         0.17779331,  0.13123691, -0.02180249],
       [ 0.0406248 , -0.0628924 ,  0.25276813,  0.09493993, -0.18715475,
        -0.04871836,  0.04059317, -0.13940312,  0.01072847, -0.00143248,
         0.28100935, -0.04627981,  0.03196833,  0.07120232,  0.07290287,
        -0.13559093,  0.02735679,  0.22925262,  0.0404184 ,  0.01314906,
         0.10446987,  0.0190053 ,  0.03544032,  0.16709638,  0.05228996,
        -0.3367106 , -0.13968703, -0.16469303,  0.23213567, -0.16272104,
         0.00153116, -0.22684756,  0.39004198, -0.17515612, -0.0731611 ,
        -0.05011011, -0.02349407,  0.00515303, -0.09741961,  0.07983034,
         0.09564134,  0.12932387,  0.09508701,  0.12182487, -0.04965768,
        -0.10650358, -0.23383772,  0.19103175],
       [ 0.01548704, -0.29555339,  0.05715664, -0.16189465,  0.03499255,
         0.21402009, -0.09664325, -0.02386762,  0.3317377 ,  0.0967191 ,
         0.00617218,  0.08791035, -0.07249293, -0.01702965,  0.28173098,
        -0.05189466,  0.16439016, -0.17383827, -0.15582241,  0.18802027,
         0.01917838,  0.07647445,  0.15948787,  0.0878301 ,  0.03346422,
         0.07002883,  0.06093212,  0.05227378, -0.0818451 ,  0.17109218,
        -0.06212406, -0.12410983,  0.33803824,  0.12105033,  0.02402613,
         0.07761155,  0.33019975, -0.02377768, -0.11400606, -0.0909552 ,
        -0.16028784, -0.17264588,  0.0084119 ,  0.14556548,  0.01698433,
         0.17410459, -0.02737463, -0.11298372],
       [ 0.3221916 , -0.13795164,  0.16254824,  0.17292848, -0.10435951,
        -0.01355793, -0.16088085,  0.09203475, -0.17928492,  0.0642034 ,
         0.01287666,  0.07464992,  0.24870317,  0.13904518,  0.07857218,
        -0.11355306, -0.12257951,  0.22196048, -0.06356272,  0.03277521,
        -0.03949503,  0.00986036,  0.09513797, -0.16556983, -0.12827548,
         0.026578  ,  0.26690841, -0.05049543,  0.04815316,  0.20526268,
        -0.14276674,  0.18441732, -0.10276154,  0.22870025,  0.11240374,
        -0.21866821,  0.09622572, -0.00426483, -0.23028791,  0.19355921,
        -0.00599831,  0.13047583,  0.16049533,  0.13316454, -0.15122548,
        -0.05988484,  0.0807161 , -0.13862035],
       [-0.20290378,  0.0447388 ,  0.00251961,  0.28006148,  0.25653204,
         0.00534883,  0.10078116,  0.02890838, -0.0326261 , -0.08573683,
         0.08485619,  0.07575557, -0.1360961 , -0.18079524,  0.15826732,
        -0.3027634 ,  0.01673756,  0.14736931, -0.04465336, -0.25784078,
        -0.12580903,  0.10712094,  0.08812711,  0.07716106,  0.03651243,
        -0.12892573,  0.01697676,  0.08949891, -0.19950908,  0.23513792,
        -0.06774111,  0.06022764, -0.11096187, -0.01119936, -0.16933256,
         0.0597085 , -0.12040415,  0.23257086,  0.08027195,  0.03882086,
        -0.21593039, -0.08365598, -0.08527714,  0.28556687, -0.2665146 ,
         0.00986508, -0.11322719,  0.06011448]], dtype=float32), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)]
1 []
2 [array([[ 0.75362301,  0.43799639],
       [ 0.98578501,  0.0380733 ],
       [-0.38638234, -0.44162703],
       [ 0.06233907, -0.50022388],
       [-0.65105438,  0.90983796],
       [ 0.00867295,  0.28238487],
       [-0.1554873 , -0.33650756],
       [-0.40741014,  0.65137649],
       [ 0.54700851, -0.79713511],
       [-0.94714022, -0.8237114 ],
       [-0.7994988 ,  0.41735601],
       [-0.24323153,  0.59699798]], dtype=float32), array([ 0.,  0.], dtype=float32)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empty layer 1 in weight printing cause by:

```
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
```